# How to delete an object from nested json in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have json object as below and i am trying to delete an object from it.

```json
{"id":1,
 "name": "abc",
 "address":
  {"add1":"1234",
   "add2":"xyz",
   "city":"TN"
   "apt": 1
}}
```

I need to delete apt from address.

I am using `object_delete(json_data,'address:apt')`. But this is not giving proper result. Can someone let me know what is way to this operation

Comment: you have syntax errors on the line ```"city"::TN"```. Is it a typo, or real data? If it is the real data then it is not a valid json.

Comment: It is just a typo mistake. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select object_insert(json_data,'address',object_delete(json_data:address::variant,'apt'),true)
```

This is giving me json data with out apt. I can update it back json_data with it.